# ObjC selector/block signature more powerful but less typesafe than anticipated? (automatic "unsafe" casting)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Consider:

```
[self.staves enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    HBStaffView * sv = (HBStaffView *) obj ;
    [sv flush] ;
}] ;
```

and:

```
[self.staves enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(HBStaffView * sv, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [sv flush] ;
}] ;
```

Both compile, and both work.

I know what is in the array I am enumerating over, so having the cast to the correct type be done for me by the compiler such that the right type is directly delivered to me how I need to use it is obviously a boon.

What is interesting though, is that here, the block signature is a "C" language signature that has nothing to do with selectors, and knows nothing (theoretically) about objects, certainly not that "id" is the superclass of everything (so to speak loosely).

Hmmm? Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax may be C syntax but the type `id` is an Objective-C type.  You couldn't use that block signature in something that was compiled as strict C rather than as Objective-C unless, maybe you add a typedef for `id` to say `void*`

Answer (score 4):

There is effectively no difference between your two pieces of code.

The `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method is declared as taking a block as a parameter where the blocks arguments are `(id, NSUInteger, BOOL*)`.   That you can declare it as a more specific *object type* of `(MyClass*, NSUInteger, BOOL*)` is simply a feature of Objective-C;  it allows a *more specific* type specifier to be substituted for the `id` parameter as long as that more specific type *is some kind of Objective-C instance reference*.

That a block is a C language feature is irrelevant.  So are C functions, yet you can pass object types to C functions, too.   In fact, Objective-C methods are really just C functions with two arguments always at the beginning;  `self` and `_cmd` (try `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));` in any method).

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it has everything to do with the fact that `NSObject` is a superclass for everything (`id` is `NSObject*`). Because `HBStaffView` inherits from `NSObject` you can think of the second version as a specialization of the first. If on the other hand, the original signature was expecting NSNumber and you tried using NSString then the code would not evenn compile. The casting is only "unsafe" at compile-time. If the objects within the array are not of the type you have declared then expect an exception to be raised at runtime as soon as you call a method an that object.

--- Edit ---

I stand corrected. `id`, as @Codify has said, is *NOT* `NSObject*` as its declaration as objc_object* might suggest. The documention mentions

> The id type defines a generic object pointer. It’s possible to use id
>   when declaring a variable, but you lose compile-time information about
>   the object.

Which could be interpreted simply as *ANY* kind of object. The remainder of the explanation remains valid.

Comment: One last nitpick: `id` is most certainly not NSObject*.  There are a more base classes in Foundation than that.

Comment: Just to complete CodaFi comment : id is typedef struct objc_object* (see objc/objc.h). NSProxy is another root class.

Comment: `id` is not only not `NSObject*`, but the two don't even work the same.   `id` means "responds to any selector ever seen ever" whereas `NSObject*` means "only responds to selectors declared on `NSObject`".

Comment: The puzzling bit to me is that the *syntax* of the block arguments is "C" syntax, not ObjC syntax, from which I am inferring (possibly wrongly?) that "C" having zero notion of what an `id` could possibly be, short of some kind of `void *` cannot possibly know that it is safe for me to cast to anything _except if it follows the C rules that any pointer to anything can be cast to `void *`._

Comment: @verec As as I said in my answer above, that a block is a C construct is irrelevant.  So are methods and C functions, yet they all can have Objective-C arguments and the type promotion/demotion rules remain consistent across them.